# Gravity Forms - Conditional Result

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a GF with 3 products at a set price. However, if the user purchases more than one, there's a $50 discount on each additional item.

EX: Product 1 = $500

User buys 2 items, $500 + $450 (total = $950). Is there a way to do this with native (or plugin) conditional logic?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this natively is to create an extra Product field that adds as a "base" fee. In your case, that fee would be $50. Then your product price would be $450 all the time. Use conditional logic to "show" the base fee when only 1 item is ordered and to "hide" the base fee when more than 1 item is ordered.